# Extract into interface

Tags: c#

I have multiple classes for doing database access, each class contains a set of methods for extracting information from the database and passing it into another object. The problems is that most of the methods extract into a different object. What would be the best way to extract this into an interface to help tidy up my code and reduce the number of database connections

example class

```
public class RequestDB
  {

    public RequestDB(string connectionStringName)
    {
        connectionString = connectionStringName;
    }


    public void UpdateRequest(AssignmentRequest request)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateAssignmentRequest", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@assignmentRequestId", SqlDbType.Int));
        cmd.Parameters["@assignmentRequestId"].Value = request.RequestID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@jobTitle", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        ...
        try
        {
            // Move to a cache class library
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Log.Write("Exception", "Unknown", "RequestDB", "UpdateRequest",    request.ToString(), ex.Message);

            throw new ApplicationException("Data source error.");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }



    public int RequestAssignment(AssignmentRequest request)
    {
        int result = 0;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("RequestAssignment", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@clientUserId", SqlDbType.Int));
        cmd.Parameters["@clientUserId"].Value = request.RequestingUserID;
        ...
        try
        {
            // Move to a cache class library
            con.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            result = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("id"));
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Log.Write("Exception", "Unknown", "RequestDB", "RequestAssignment", request.ToString(), ex.Message);

            throw new ApplicationException("Data source error.");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public List<AssignmentRequest> GetAllAssignmentRequests()
    {
        var result = new List<AssignmentRequest>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAssignmentRequests", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        try
        {
            // Move to a cache class library
            con.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                result.Add(new AssignmentRequest()
                               {
                                   RequestID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("requestId")),
                                   RequestingUserID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("clientUserId")),
                                   ...
                               });
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Log.Write("Exception", "Unknown", "RequestDB", "GetAllAssignmentRequests", "", ex.Message);

            throw new ApplicationException("Data source error.");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public AssignmentRequest GetAssignmentRequestById(int requestId)
    {
        var result = new AssignmentRequest();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAssignmentRequestByID", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@requestId", SqlDbType.Int));
        cmd.Parameters["@requestId"].Value = requestId;
        try
        {
            // Move to a cache class library
            con.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
                result = new AssignmentRequest()
                {
                    RequestID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("requestId")),
                    RequestingUserID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("clientUserId")),
                    JobTitle = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("jobTitle")),
                    Department = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("department")),
                    ...
                };

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Log.Write("Exception", "Unknown", "RequestDB", "GetAssignmentRequestById", requestId.ToString(), ex.Message);

            throw new ApplicationException("Data source error.");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }


    public List<AssignmentRequest> GetRequestHistoryByClientUserId(int clientUserId)
    {
        var result = new List<AssignmentRequest>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetRequestHistoryByClientUserId", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientUserId", clientUserId);
        try
        {
            // Move to a cache class library
            con.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                var request = new AssignmentRequest()
                                  {
                                      RequestID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("requestId")),
                                      RequestingUserID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("clientUserId")),
                                      JobTitle = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("jobTitle")),
                                      ...
                result.Add(request);

            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Log.Write("Exception", "Unknown", "RequestDB", "GetRequestHistoryByClientUserId", "", ex.Message);

            throw new ApplicationException("Data source error.");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use generics, something like this:

```
public interface Repository<K, T> {
    List<T> find();
    T find(K key);
    K save(T value);
    void update(T value);
    void delete(T value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen several similar questions like these. My suggestion is DON'T rush to interface design.

Are those classes from your own code ? Can be modified ?

I have found that a good alternative techique to your problem, instead of rushing to interfaces, is to make a superclass or group of superclasses from the classes / objects that share common behavior (methods, properties). Later, they can be  migrated to an interface.

Step 1 (How classes are now) :

```
public class MSSQLConnection
{
  public void DoSomething() { ... }
}

public class XMLConnection
{
  public void TrySomething() { ... }
}

public class OracleConnection
{
    public void MakeSomething() { ... }
}
```

Step 2 (Rename / Refactor same ids.):

```
public class MSSQLConnection
{
  public void DoSomething() { ... }
}

public class XMLConnection
{
  public void DoSomething() { ... }
}

public class OracleConnection
{
    public void DoSomething() { ... }
}
```

Step 3 (Make common superclasss) :

```
public class BaseConnection
{
    public virtual void DoSomething() { ... }
}

public class MSSQLConnection: BaseConnection
{
  public override void DoSomething() { ... }
}

public class XMLConnection: BaseConnection
{
  public override void DoSomething() { ... }
}

public class OracleConnection: BaseConnection
{
    public override void DoSomething() { ... }
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use generics to create a common interface as pointed out by duffymo.
To share the database connection across your different database access classes
use constructor injection:

```
public class ExampleRepository1
{
  private SqlConnection _conn;
  public ExampleRepository(SqlConnection conn)
  {
    _conn = oConnection;
  }
}

public class ExampleRepository2
{
  private SqlConnection _conn;
  public ExampleRepository2(SqlConnection conn)
  {
    _conn = conn;
  }
}

// Share the database connection:

var conn = new SqlConnection(...);

try
{
  conn.Open();

  // You could also begin a transaction here
  // Use conn.BeginTransation()

  var repo1 = new ExampleRepository1(conn);
  var repo2 = new ExampleRepository2(conn);

  repo1.Find(...);
  repo2.Delete(...)
}
finally
{
  conn.Close();
}
```